# Why is my toString method returning null in an array of elements in java?

Tags: java, arrays, null, tostring

I an array that contains "a b c d e".
I then use a reverse method to swap the elements in the array to "e d c b a"

I'm trying to print out the items contained in an array using this toString method:

```
public String toString()
{
    String s = "";
    if(isEmpty())
    {
        s = "List is empty";
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < numItems; i++)
    {
        s += items[i] + " ";
    }//end for
    return s;
}//end of toString
```

The string s came out to be "null e d c b"

I'm not sure why, but i think it has to involve initializing s to be "".

Here is my reverse method as well if that helps:

```
public void reverseList()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < items.length/2; i++)
    {
        Object temp = items[i];
        items[i] = items[items.length-i-1];
        items[items.length-i-1] = temp;
    }//end for
    System.out.println("List reversed");
}//end of reverseList
```

And here is the add method for the array:

```
public void add(int index, Object item)
throws  ListIndexOutOfBoundsException
{
    if (numItems > items.length)//fixes implementaion error
    {
        throw new ListException("ListException on add");
    }  // end if
    if (index >= 0 && index <= numItems)
    {
        // make room for new element by shifting all items at
        // positions >= index toward the end of the
        // list (no shift if index == numItems+1)
        for (int pos = numItems-1; pos >= index; pos--)
        {
            items[pos+1] = items[pos];
        } // end for
        // insert new item
        items[index] = item;
        numItems++;
        System.out.println("Item " + item + " inserted into position " + index + " in the list.");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Position specified is out of range!");
    }  // end if
} //end add
```

Thanks!

Comment: Prove to us that your array contains those elements.

Comment: Edit your question. Please don't post code in comments.

Comment: Now you've shown you can reverse an array. But you still haven't shown that the array contains those elements.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Is this more informative?

Comment: At this point, we are just debugging your code. Please do this yourself. Or provide a fully reproducible, short-as-possible, example we can run that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I'll just try and debug it again and see what I find. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis You were right, the reverse method switches every element in the list, even null ones. So I think there is something wrong with the condition in the loop.

Comment: Good luck! (Always try to do as much of your own debugging as you can before posting. You can then demonstrate what you've ruled. You might even find the solution yourself.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is most likely with your reverse swap and not your toString method due to the fact that the reverse swap has properly gotten EDCB but if off-set by one with the null.

*I'm sorry I failed my spell backwards test Q_Q*

Comment: what does EDBC means here?

Comment: _East Doncaster Baptist Church_ (had to google it)

Comment: @jangroth for love of moses haha I cannot stop laughing

Comment: @Compass I've already determined that it is not the reverse swap method because I've debugged it.  However when I went line by line in the toString method, it assigned null to s.

Comment: @KickButtowski the elements in the array are "a b c d e". When the array is reversed the elements are in the order of "e d c b a"

Answer (score 0):

Initialize s to be "" will not cause you output null for item[0]. The reason caused this output is the reverse() method that you use is wrong.

Comment: I edited the post to contain the reverse method. I don't think that there is anything wrong with it because I tested it and the elements were in the right place.

Comment: I think you need provide more information. I can't find anything just from the code you post.